# Extra option in editor

Tags: custom-field, visual-editor

I'm sure there's an easy solution to this, but I'm wondering how to add custom input fields in the Wordpress editor.

My goal is to have an image uploader to the right of the main editor, when an image is uploaded, it puts the image url into a `custom field` that I an access in my theme.

What's the best way to go about this? I've researched & tried plugins, but I'd rather create my own as they all produced bugs.

Thanks for any help/advice.

Shane

Comment: Search through the [tag:custom-field] archives. If it brings nothing up, you can still add ["media"](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bcustom-field%5D+media) to your search string.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/attaching-files-to-your-posts-using-wordpress-custom-meta-boxes-part-1/) tutorial will help you.

#### EDIT: some code in case the original source gets lost.

**1st)** Add the meta box to all the post types we need

```
function wpse31877_add_custom_meta_boxes() 
{
    foreach ( array( 'post', 'page' ) as $post_type )
    {
        add_meta_box(
             'wp_custom_attachment'
            ,'Custom Attachment'
            ,'wpse31877_custom_attachment'
            ,$post_type
            ,'side'
        );
    }
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'wpse31877_add_custom_meta_boxes' );
```

**2nd)** Set up our callback (the content of the meta box)

```
function wpse31877_custom_attachment() 
{
    // validate and secure our upload
    wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename(__FILE__), 'wpse31877_custom_attachment_nonce' );

    printf( 
         '<p class="description">%s</p>%s'
        ,__( 'Upload your PDF here.', 'your_custom_textdomain' )
        ,'<input type="file" id="wp_custom_attachment" name="wp_custom_attachment" value="" size="25">'
);
}
```

**3rd)** Save our data

```
function wpse31977_save_custom_meta_data( $id ) 
{
    // security verification
    if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['wpse31977_custom_attachment_nonce'], plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) )
    {
        return $id;
    }

    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) AND DOING_AUTOSAVE )
    {
        return $id;
    }

    if ( 'page' === $_POST['post_type'] )
    {
        if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_page', $id ) )
        {
            return $id;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $id ) )
        {
                return $id;
        }
    }

    // Make sure the file array isn't empty
    if ( ! empty( $_FILES['wp_custom_attachment']['name'] ) ) 
    {
        // Setup the array of supported file types. In this case, it's just PDF.
        $supported_types = array( 'application/pdf' );

        // Get the file type of the upload
        $arr_file_type = wp_check_filetype( basename( $_FILES['wp_custom_attachment']['name'] ) );
        $uploaded_type = $arr_file_type['type'];

        // Check if the type is supported. If not, throw an error.
        if ( in_array( $uploaded_type, $supported_types ) )
        {
            // Use the WordPress API to upload the file
            $upload = wp_upload_bits( $_FILES['wp_custom_attachment']['name'], null, file_get_contents( $_FILES['wp_custom_attachment']['tmp_name'] ) );

            if ( isset( $upload['error'] ) AND 0 != $upload['error'] )
            {
                wp_die( sprintf( __( 'There was an error uploading your file. The error is: %s', 'your_textdomain' ), $upload['error'] ) );
            }
            else
            {
                add_post_meta( $id, 'wp_custom_attachment', $upload );
                update_post_meta( $id, 'wp_custom_attachment', $upload );       
            }

        }
        else
        {
            wp_die( __( "The file type that you've uploaded is not a PDF.", 'your_textdomain' );
        }

    }

} // end save_custom_meta_data
add_action( 'save_post', 'wpse31877_save_custom_meta_data' );
```

**4th)** Display the data from the meta box.

```
echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'wp_custom_attachment', true );
```